# How to change low contrast highlight in default vim color scheme

Tags: vim, vi

I am using vim with the default color scheme on dark background, but in many cases, the white font is highlighted with light pink color, making it hard to read. How do I fix this (change highlight color) in the default color scheme?

Here is an example of the problem:
[image: example of highlight issue in vim]

Comment: What does `:set bg?` say?

Comment: It seems that _background=light_, so i changed it to _background=dark_ in vimrc. Is there a way to edit the colors in the default color scheme? I prefer the default, but i would like to change some of the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @AlexTsolovikos You can override the colours by `:highlight` command. You can write these settings in your .vimrc. Using autocmd, like `autocmd ColorScheme default hi Normal ctermbg=blue`, your changes will always be there when you `:colorscheme default`. Or, you could make your own colorscheme based on default.  Grab the `default.vim` file, modify it, then place it under ~/.vim/colors/` with your preferred name.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the colors displayed with the :highlight command, which can be called from your `vimrc`.  The documentation is really quite good for this, and can be read here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight.